# Scala Lift Database connection for postgresql

Tags: scala, lift

I'm doing the Lift In Action by Timothy Perrett and the book is a bit confusing on db connection.

Here's the link:
https://github.com/timperrett/lift-in-action/blob/master/chapter-3/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala

The confusing part, is JNDI. I do not have a java background so it's a bit confusing and the prop files are confusing too. It's a bit similar the config files or ini files but still there's a lot going on that I don't understand.

I've found another tutorial:
http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-8.html
@ 8.1.2 Setting Up the Database Connection

This is a bit different. Which is more familiar to me coming from a PHP background.

So what's the difference? And is there any advantages between the two different methods? And also the second method doesn't check for if the connection isn't establish, how do I check for it? Or is there any snippet of code you guys can provide to show me the best practice of fail over?

oh! The load shark pattern is used to make sure that only one db connection is use right?

Thank you for your time.

edit:
I believe the check for connection is establish or not is in the database object already on newConnection in the DBVendor object. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

Put your database configuration in `./src/main/resources/default.props` in the form of:

```
db.class=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql:[//host[:port]]/database
db.user=user
db.pass=password
```

Of course, you need to provide the correct values for your database.

## the long story

If JNDI is confusing, you can ignore it for now.  It is a [part of Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html) which is useful if you're trying to configure production applications to run on an application server, but not necessary.

[Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) are an age-old method in Java for handling configuration.  A properties file (which is usually named `.props` or `.properties`) is just a list of name/value pairs.

Lift provides a [`Props`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/util/Props%24.html) object for conveniently providing different properties files for different environments.  [The wiki](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Properties) has a good write-up for how it works, but basically you can specify different properties for any combination of run mode (test, staging, production, etc.), hostname and username.

Now, breaking down Tim Perrett's code:

1. Check whether a JNDI connection is available.  Unless you run an app server and set that up, it won't be.  Not a big deal if it's not.
2. If there's no JNDI, it uses the `Database` object to configure the data source.
3. The `Database` object uses Lift's `Props` object to load the values from the whichever `.props` file best matches the system you're running on.  If you only provide `default.props`, those are the values that will be used.
4. If there is no properties file, or it doesn't contain database config keys, then the `openOr` provides default values for using [an H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/).

Lift already does its own connection management, which typically means a different database connection per-thread.  If a connection cannot be established, you'll get `SQLException` from your data access code.